# Groupby with conditions

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['A','B','B','B','C','C'], 
                   'Subcategory': ['X','X','Y','Y','Z','Z'], 
                   'Values': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

which I use `groupby` to summarize -

```
`df.groupby('Category')['Values'].agg({np.size, np.mean, np.median})` 

            size    mean    median
    Category            
    A           1       1.0     1.0
    B           3       3.0     3.0
    C           2       5.5     5.5
```

**Objective: In addition to the above, show additional `groupby` by subcategory 'X'** to create below output:

```
    ALL Subcategory                 Only Subcategory 'X'
    size    mean    median          size    mean    median
    Category            
    A           1       1.0     1.0             1       1       1
    B           3       3.0     3.0             1       2       2
    C           2       5.5     5.5             0       0       0
```

My solution currently is to create two `groupby`, `to_frame()` then `pd.merge` them. Is there a better way? Thanks!

```
df.groupby('Category')['Values'].agg({np.size, np.mean, np.median}) 

df[df['Subcategory']=='X'].groupby('Category')['Values'].agg({np.size, np.mean, np.median})
```